# In C#, how can I know the number of frames of a TIFF file without actually loading the file?

Tags: c#, .net, frame, tiff

I want to know how many frames a TIFF picture contains. However, to minimize the execution time, I would like to know this information without actually loading the full file. How can I achieve this?

For your information, I am using the following code right now:

```
FileStream mystream = new FileStream("mypicture.tif", FileMode.Open);
_Image _currentImg = Image.FromStream(mystream );
mystream.Close();

FrameDimension myframeDimensions = new
    FrameDimension(_currentImg.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
Int32 numberOfFrames = _currentImg.GetFrameCount(myframeDimensions );
```

Comment: You will likely have to implement bits and pieces of a TIFF decoder, google for the TIFF file format specification.

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at the spec, but I think this is one of the easier things to determine.  The pages are saved like a linked list so it's just a matter of reading offsets from the correct location and looping.